# How to mount a Vuetify Component from a simple HTML Page?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vuetify.js

Hey guys I am stucked with this problem:
I have created some components with Vuetify 2.x/Webpack and want to use them in a simple HTML Webpage not based on Vue at all.
It should be like this: The user clicks a button an then a function is called that creates and mounts a component to the dom.

My idea was to create a main.js with this content:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import TicketsView from '@/views/tickets-view.vue'

Vue.component('TicketsView', TicketsView)

function mount (id) {
  return new Vue({
    el: id,
    vuetify
  })
}

export default mount
```

Is this possible or the right way?

Creating a library and using it in a demo.html seems not to work.

Yes I can see this. The name of the lib is vue-component-library.umd.js and my demo.html created by webpack looks like this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>vue-component-library demo</title>
<script src="./vue-component-library.umd.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./vue-component-library.css">


<script>
console.log(window['vue-component-library'])
</script>
```

but it gives me

```
vue-component-library.umd.js:27263 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extend')
    at Module.fb15 (vue-component-library.umd.js:27263:104)
    at __webpack_require__ (vue-component-library.umd.js:30:30)
    at vue-component-library.umd.js:94:18
    at vue-component-library.umd.js:97:10
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (vue-component-library.umd.js:9:35)
    at vue-component-library.umd.js:10:3
```

Any idea?

Comment: This isn't very different a lot from how Vue normally works. It's loaded on some page, which is normally blank index.html, but could be anything else. It's unknown what's your setup. E.g. in Vue CLI should be bundled as a library in order to expose `mount`, or you could expose it as a global to window manually, which is a blunt approach

Comment: And how is it done?
I am looking for a solution that dynamically create a TicketList created with a TicketList.vue file depending on VuetifyJs. So Webpack creates a bundle and I want to use this bundle to show the TicketList when the user hits a button in a normal HTML page.

Comment: As I said, this is specific to your setup, which isn't described. Basically, Webpack should bundle UMD module that exposes `window.YourLibName` as main.js exports to other scripts on the page, and so `window.YourLibName.default` function

Comment: Yes I can see this. The name of the lib is vue-component-library.umd.js and my demo.html created by webpack looks like this:

see above

Comment: It's unknown what the error refers to, could be because Vue CDN script is expected to be loaded (`extend` could refer to Vue.extend), but I don't see this from the question. You can check relevant locations in call stack by clicking on them. If the problem persists, please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's impossible to solve the problem without knowing the details